# How to insert dynamic URL parameters in HTML (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a marketing landing page that would take parameters in a URL and then display them in the HTML of an id on the page. Right now, I have every text placeholder defined in addition to each parameter from the URL.

The code below is working fine, but is there a way to remove the redundancies so that if **any** id matches the name of a parameter in the URL (e.g. a span has id "city" is automatically matched with the parameter "city"), they recognize and update the inner HTML? Thanks for any help.

```
const queryString = window.location.search;

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);

const company_text = document.getElementById("company");
const company = urlParams.get('company');
if (company != null){
    company_text.innerHTML = company;
}

const city_text = document.getElementById("city");
const city = urlParams.get('city');
if (city != null){
    city_text.innerHTML = city;
}
```

*Edited to update parameter names for clarity*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by iterating over a list of all URL parameters and changing the HTML content of elements with the correct IDs.

```js
var parameters = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

for (const parameter of parameters) {
  document.querySelectorAll(`[id=${parameter[0]}]`).forEach(element => {
    element.innerHTML = parameter[1];
  });
}
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Best Regards,

Comment: This worked perfectly. Wish I could buy you a coffee (if there's a way, let me know). Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could be of assistance!

Comment: Realized this isn't working for pages where the ID is being used more than once (it's updating only the first instance). Is there a way to have it apply to all instances? Thinking we'd need to change to use a target other than an ID...

Comment: I edited the code to work with multiple elements of the same ID. The algorithm iterates over the URL search parameters and then iterates over and modifies each element with a particular ID.

Answer (score 1):

You could put something like this at the end of your page

```
for(const [id, val] of urlParams.entries()) {
    const htmlElement = document.getElementById(id);
    if(htmlElement) {
        htmlElement.innerHTML = val;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the same parameter can  appear more than one time in the query string (e.g. `?x=1&x=2`). In that case there will be two entries with the same id.

[Ref for entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/entries).

Comment: up voted, but is there any advantage to using entries over the [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/forEach) method?

Comment: `entries()` returns the iterator and is equivalent to iterate the object itself. It could have been omited here. As for `forEach` method, it's just a different way to iterate on the values. I prefer `for of` construct but I guess it's a matter of opinion.